# Android repeating notification without Alarm Manager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I have been using alarm manager for firing up notification when alarm is called. But the problem is that I have to implement particular permision to use Alarm and the user might not like this hindrance on our part.

Is there any other way to show repeating notification for ex. in crossy roads, where I don't have to use Alarm manager to repeat notification. Also I am not interested in utilizing push notification ( to avoid useless hassle).

In short:

1.) I want to notify user to start my app in regular interval

2.)Without using alarm manager and push notification.

Thanks!!!

Comment: "But the problem is that I have to implement particular permision to use Alarm" -- what permission are you thinking of? Bear in mind that there are no other reliable options than the ones you are dismissing, and on Android M even the `AlarmManager` approach will have issues.

Comment: The permission to use Alarm Manager or set alarm permission.

Comment: I think the user will be skeptic about this permission.That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to implement particular permision to use Alarm

No, you do not.

> The permission to use Alarm Manager or set alarm permission.

That is only needed by the `setAlarmClock()` method, at most. The regular `AlarmManager` methods (e.g., `set()`, `setRepeating()`) do not need this permission.

Alarms get wiped out on a reboot. If you wanted to re-establish those alarms automatically on a reboot, you would need the `BOOT_COMPLETED` permission to arrange to get control at that time. However, you might wish to re-establish the alarms at some other time (e.g., when the user next runs your app), and so `BOOT_COMPLETED` is optional.

Comment: I was asking that whether there is any way to set repeating notfication except for alarm manager like in some apps ex. crossy road ( they don't use alarm. I have seen from there permissions).

Comment: @uday: As I wrote in my answer, there are no permissions needed to use most methods on `AlarmManager`.

Comment: thanks commonware the "problem" is solved now. but i have another problem relating to alarm manager. do i need to post a new question or can you solve it here only.

Comment: @uday: "do i need to post a new question" -- yes, please.